# Issues with Merge Statement (specifically update portion)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having issues with getting my merge command to work. What i have figured out is that it is not allowing for multiple columns to be updated at once. Is there any way around this?

The error that appears is

```
"Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "s.AddressCaption" could not be bound."
```

I am positive that both the server and column exist and are properly named. If I try to delete S.AddressCaption then the next column is the error that pops up.

It only appears to recognize s.descr

Here is the query:

```
 MERGE Payor as T
Using dss.RCSQL.dbo.Payors as S
ON t.code = s.code
WHEN MATCHED and (s.descr <> t.descr or s.AddressCaption <> t.[AddressCaption] or S.Address <> t.address or S.address2 <> t.address2 or 
s.city <> t.city or s.state <> t.state or s.zip <> t.zip or s.ContactPhone <> t.ContactPhone or s.systemID <> t.systemID or s.notes <> t.notes or
s.notes <> t.notes or s.fax <> t.fax or s.medicarepart <> t.medicarepart or s.category <> t.category or s.PayorKey <> t.Payorkey)
THEN
UPDATE SET t.descr = s.descr, s.AddressCaption = t.[AddressCaption],  S.Address = t.address,  S.address2 = t.address2,  
s.city = t.city,  s.state = t.state,  s.zip = t.zip,  s.ContactPhone = t.ContactPhone,  s.systemID = t.systemID,  s.notes = t.notes, 
s.notes = t.notes,  s.fax = t.fax,  s.medicarepart = t.medicarepart,  s.category = t.category,  s.PayorKey = t.Payorkey
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (code,descr, [AddressCaption], Address, Address2, City, State, Zip, ContactPhone, systemID, Notes, Fax, MedicarePart, category, PayorKey)
VALUES (s.code,s.descr, s.AddressCaption, s.Address, s.Address2, s.City, s.State, s.Zip, s.ContactPhone, s.systemID, 
s.Notes, s.Fax, s.MedicarePart, s.category, s.PayorKey);
```

Comment: You can't update both tables in a merge statement, only the target.  With the descr update, you are setting t = s.  In the rest you are setting s = t.

Comment: Ah thank you, i did not realize it would matter if i had t=s or s=t. After changing all columns to t=s, the error stopped and it showed number of rows affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per. Dave.Gugg solution was to be consistent with having the targettable.[attribute] first and then the sourcetable.[attribute] second.

```
t.col1 = s.col1, t.col2 = s.col2 ...
```